# Why does textstat_simil() with method "cosine" returns NA

Tags: r, cosine-similarity, quanteda

I am computing cosine similarity over two `dfm` objects. One is my reference object which has dimensions 5 x 4,728 while the second `dfm` is my target object and has dimensions 2,325,329 x 40,595.

What I don't understand is why `textstat_simil()` returns NAs. I tried reproducing the "issue" but no luck so far. You can find the data at the following Dropbox links. Be advised that the target `dfm` contains only the first document.

1. [Reference dfm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jsaguv9hatl1hkr/reference_dfm.RData?dl=0)
2. [Target dfm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tn9b77ipxrfypzy/target_dfm.RData?dl=0)

This is the code I am using. `dfm_match()` augments my reference `dfm` to match the number of features of the target object.

```
library(quanteda)

# make sure you load the two required dfms

reference_dfm = dfm_match(reference_dfm, featnames(target_dfm))
textstat_simil( target_dfm, reference_dfm, method = "cosine")

#> textstat_simil object; method = "cosine"
#>         negative slightly_negative neutral slightly_positive positive
#> text1.1       NA                NA      NA                NA       NA
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `target_dfm` is entirely sparse (all 0s), so you can't calculate cosine similarity.

```r
target_df <- convert(target_dfm, "data.frame")
sum(target_df[,2:ncol(target_df)] > 0)
#> 0
```

You can also note that when you print the `dfm` to console it says it is "100.0% sparse". Here is a `dfm` 1 value away from being sparse, and the calculation works.

```r
test_dfm <- dfm(corpus("adds"))
test_dfm <- dfm_match(test_dfm, featnames(target_dfm))
textstat_simil(test_dfm, reference_dfm2, method = "cosine")
#> textstat_simil object; method = "cosine"
#>         negative slightly_negative neutral slightly_positive positive
#> text1.1        0                 0       0                 0        0
```